# what means the redundacy of a code?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I was reading a paper about a transposition and single deletion error correcting code and they claim that the redundancy of the code *was only* $log(6n-3)$ bits.

But *what does that means?* I was trying to get that from the proof of that fact but what they proved instead was that

*there exists a such (with the structure they propose) code whose redundancy is at most* $log(6n-3)$ *bits*

and in the proof itself they just said that the cardinality of the code is greater or equal than $\frac{2^n}{6n-3}$.

How does that proved the hiposesis?

Also, if I have my own code how do I compute the redundancy (or a resonable bound on it?)

Thanks

Comment: I suppose it means that the length of the code is $\log_2(6n-3)$ times the length of the message...

Comment: the question is badly written but it usually means the length of the codeword is $\log_2(6n-3)$ plus the length of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes $\log_2 M$ bits to uniquely specify a member of a set of cardinality $M.$

The collection of all binary vectors of length $n$ clearly requires all of these $n$ bits. It has redundancy zero, where *redundancy* is defined as $$R=n-\log_2 M.$$

Thus redundancy at most $\log_2 (6n-3)$ means
$$
n-\log_2 \# C \leq \log_2 (6n-3),
$$
or
$$
\log_2(2^n)-\log_2(6n-3) \leq \log_2\#C,
$$
leading to 
$$
\frac{2^n}{6n-3} \leq \#C.
$$